# Rails not getting value from associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have 2 tables named : `order_items` and `orders` in schema. Following is sample of my schema

```
create_table "orders", force: :cascade do |t|
 t.string "first_name"
 t.string "last_name"
 t.datetime "created_at", null: false
 t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
 t.string "token"
 t.decimal "sub_total"
 t.string "mobile"
 t.string "address"
```

and

```
create_table "order_items", force: :cascade do |t|
 t.integer "order_id", null: false
 t.integer "item_id", null: false
 t.integer "quantity", null: false
 t.decimal "price", precision: 15, scale: 2, null: false
 t.datetime "created_at", null: false
 t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
end
```

For Models,

`order.rb`

```
has_many :order_items
```

`order_item.rb`

```
belongs_to :order
belongs_to :item
```

I thought I would have been able to get `Order.orderitem.quantity` with this association, but not able to get it. I get error as `undefined method 'orderitems' for nil:NilClass`

Comment: @JagdeepSingh sorry you are right, I removed the Order#items. Yes there is an Item model as well.

Comment: _"I thought I would have been able to get Order.orderitem.quantity"_ - No, you can't. There is no class method `orderitem` defined on class `Order`.

Comment: Please paste the complete sequence of statements you are running before you see this error.

Comment: I am just trying to get it in my rails console

Comment: @SujanJoshi even in console, you must be typing something. What is that _something_?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try `Order.first.order_items`
this will return all the order items for first order

then you can loop through them

```
Order.first.order_items.each do |item|
  item.quantity
  ....
end
```

or take the item out with index

```
items = Order.first.order_items
items[0].quantity
```